# Loop for recently (updated_post_meta) posts?

Tags: php, post-meta

I'm trying to create a simple loop for recently updated post meta_key.

Basically, let's say someone liked a post.

When like was clicked, that updated post `meta_key` 'like' value.

I want to display on the sidebar a loop with newest liked posts.

Is that possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

**P.S.** I know how to create a function action that does something, when post meta data was updated.

But I don't need that. I want to show a simple loop with recently liked (meta updated) posts.

Comment: You could add an additional meta, something like `last liked`, every time someone likes the post update that field with the current datetime (mysql format). Now when retriving the posts filter by that custom meta (last liked) date

Comment: That's actually a great idea. Good logic. I think that would do the job. Not really familiar with the mysql datetime format, but I'll try to find out. Thanks @Buttered_Toast!

Comment: Just a quick update. Made it working! ;) thanks again @Buttered_Toast